# .rvmrc is not read in gnome-terminal

Tags: ruby, rvm, gnome-terminal, rvmrc

In one directory I have these files:

```
$ ls -1a
.
..
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
.rvmrc
test.rb
```

but `.rvmrc` file is not read when we change to this directory.

I have configured gnome-terminal as this page say: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

It seems to be disabled as could be using `rvm_project_rvmrc=0` in `/etc/rvmrc` or `~/.rmvrc`.

How can I enable .rvmrc load when I change its directory?

Comment: run: `rvm use .` in the project path, does it change anything?

Answer (score 0):

switch value of "Run commands as login shell" in your terminal preferences. Should help.